# nativescript drawer navigation angular - how to navigate?

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

I'm new in nativescript but have an experience in angular. 
I'm using this template for my first app:

https://github.com/NativeScript/template-drawer-navigation-ng

I want to navigate inside module, example:
in /settings
i want:
/settings/card
/settings/general
etc...

When i create a component and put in setting component i don't see the action-bar and i don't know how to navigate.

I want able to navigate inside the components in the drawer.

Please can someone explain me how to achieve that?

Comment: The template should work as it's. If you have modified it to add more modules, please share the updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place a `page-router-outlet` inside your drawer content, then all your routes will get a ActionBar and loaded inside the content area.

Comment: Ok it's work. And how I navigate? I want to go back page and I throw me the the home component.

Comment: If you have the routers configured properly, back method on router extension should take you to previous route / component.